# How to handle different types which use same controller, actions and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have one model Contract and it jas 2 types
1) Tax
2) Labor

I used enum for storing this 2 types.

There are 2 menus from where user can go to tax and labor contracts and do whatever action he wanted.

here is my route file

```
scope '/tax' do
        resources :clients, as: :tax_client do
          get 'contract_dashboard', on: :collection
        end
        resources :contracts, except: [:destroy] do
          collection do
            get 'change_contract_dashboard'
            get 'change_contract'
          end
          put 'update_status'
        end
      end
      scope '/labor' do
        resources :clients, as: :labor_client do
          get 'contract_dashboard', on: :collection
        end
        resources :contracts, except: [:destroy] do
          collection do
            get 'change_contract_dashboard'
            get 'change_contract'
            # get 'contract_lists(/:status)' => "contracts#contract_lists",as: :list
          end
          put 'update_status'
        end
      end
```

The thing is now I have different states in the contract like draft, request, start, end etc. There minor different change in view.

Both have the same controller, actions and view. but routes are different like tax/contracts/new, labor/contracts/new. in the form I pass contract type in the hidden field based on URL.

Now when I want to know whether I get a request for tax contract or labor contract, I have to check request.url to know the type of contract. As per my opinion, There should be any different technique to handle this kind of system.

Is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance could be a nice solution to your problem. This is what I'd do:

1. Create two new classes that inherit from your contract model:

```rb
# app/models/contracts/tax.rb
class Contracts::Tax < Contract 
  # Tax related code
end

# app/models/contracts/labor.rb
class Contracts::Labor < Contract
  # Labor related code
end
```

2. This allows you to build dedicated routes for those resources:

```rb
scope module: :contracts do 
  resources :taxes
  resources :labors 
end
```

3. You'd have to split controllers as well

```rb
# app/controllers/contracts/taxes_controller.rb
class Contracts::TaxesController < ActionController
  # controller actions for taxes
end

# app/controllers/contracts/labors_controller.rb
class Contracts::LaborsController < ActionController
  # controller actions for labors
end
```

This might seem redundant but it allows for a clear separation of concerns. You can use helpers like `form_for` in your views that will map you Tax.new and Labor.new instances to the correct controller. Since the controller are separated you'll know automatically if it's a Tax or a Labor, no need to check the request.url anymore.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What about routes? should i use scope after implementing inheritance? if i want to access both types of contracts in single page should i create a separate contracts controller?

Comment: Do i need to take type field in contracts table?

Comment: Since both Labor And Tax are contracts you can still access both on a single page. You can use a `type` field in the database to implement [Single Table Inheritance](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance)

Comment: Thank you so much, just one thing i want to say, i am not creating separate folder in model. and i written directly `class Tax < Contract;end`. will it distrub anything? i will create separate folder in controllers

Comment: It will not disturb anything, it's just a preference of mine to keep related code together :)

Comment: Yes, it should be, but what i am saying there is little tricky part, it is not related to this question. Can i ask here?

Comment: Sure, go on, I'll see what i can do

Comment: I have one parent model (Client) for this 2 types contracts, 1) Tax 2) Labor. Client has many contracts. it can be tax or labor. Now when i want to create new contract, at that time , Client will also create and i have to take contract as nested attributes. so its again creating lots of duplicate code, just because of this type

Comment: Is there any better way to create a good system for this situation?